# C# Process.GetProcessById(4) throws System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, process, module

I am writing a piece of code whereby I am to iterate through the list of modules loaded by the System process (PID : 4). The following is the code I am using to achieve it.

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessById(4);
foreach (ProcessModule pMod in process.Modules)
{
    Console.Write(pMod.FileName + "   ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

This code is throwing an error of System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, whenever it is trying to evaluate the list of Modules. In effect, any property read or method call is throwing the same error. Any other process is working fine and it is able to list all the modules correctly. Could anyone shed light on what might be causing this behavior.

Comment: As far as I know, process of id: 4 will be a System process in which it has "system" integrity, as a matter of fact, there are a lot of other processes that depends on it. You can't terminate it as well, even if you have administrator rights using a cmd. I suppose it's just you can't have access to it's modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `System` "process" (with PID 4 on Windows machines) is actually *not* a process at all, it denotes a group of processes that have SYSTEM integrity.

Try to work with a real process PID (for instance, run Internet Explorer, and use it's PID) instead, see if you`ll get the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The system process is not a real user mode process, it is the Windows kernel (for want of a better description). Therefore it cannot be examined as if it were a normal process.